# Why won't it let me pass this list?

Tags: c#

I have a list in the Students class that is passed to the Grades class.
However, once the methods in the Students class finish, it goes back to this "main menu" where they have the option to enter grades. Essentially I need to pass this list from the Students Class, back to the Controller class, and then to the Grades Class. How would I go about this?

```
Students get = new Students( );
Grades grades = new Grades( );
Search run = new Search( );

do 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please select assessment category: ");
  Console.WriteLine("________________________________________________________________________________");
  Console.WriteLine(" ");
  Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tPlease make a selection 1-4: ");
  Console.Write("\n\t\t\t1. Assignments.");
  Console.Write("\n\t\t\t2. Discussion Topics.");
  Console.Write("\n\t\t\t3. Exams.");
  Console.Write("\n\t\t\t4. Individual Project.");
  Console.Write("\n\t\t\t5. Go Back to main menu.");
  Console.WriteLine("");  
  Console.WriteLine("___________________________________________________");

category = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine( ));

switch ( decision )
    {
     case 1:
         Console.Clear( );
         get.AddStudent();
         break;
     case 2:
         Console.Clear( );
         grades.EnterGrades(List<string> addedStudents);
         break;
     case 3:
         Console.Clear( );
         run.StudentSearch( );
         break;
     case 4:
         retry = "no";
         Console.Clear();
         break;
     default:
         Console.WriteLine("\nThat is not a valid option.");
         Console.WriteLine("Would you like to retry? Type 'yes' or 'no'.");
         retry = Console.ReadLine();
         Console.Clear();
         break;
     }

}while (retry != "no");
```

Comment: Can we see your main menu class?

Comment: @john you're looking at most of the main menu class. The above code is wrapped in a `while (true)` that has a `var decision = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` as the first statement. Takes me right back to 1997 :D

Comment: Michael, I honestly didn't mean to be as derisive as my comment probably came across. We all started somewhere and most of us fondly remember the things we struggled with just as you do now. The "infinite loop main menu" I would in fact consider a true classic.

Comment: That being said, your code indeed has problems that, if explained in depth, would exceed the scope of a stackoverflow question. If you want, I'll happily walk you through some of those in a chat.

Comment: I updated my code. It's not an infinite loop. I just didn't add all of it to try to save time. This final is due in 1 hour and I'm already F%$#d. My bad.

Comment: The chat offer still stands ;)

Comment: Thanks @vzwick. I'll take you up on that tomorrow if you're around. I don't know how to chat or send anything privately on here. If you want to send me your email or something we can just do it that way? I'm exhausted, still have to eat dinner, and get two kids to bed. Thanks again. I appreciate it.

Comment: chat.stackoverflow.com - just create a room on there and invite me. I'm unfortunately going to bed now and going to be abroad until mid next week with rather intermittent internet access. Still, if feedback isn't time critical, I'm happy to help. Don't let the final screw up your time with the kids ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can't declare the variable where you pass it. Try:

```
 case 2:
     Console.Clear( );
     List<string> addedStudents = new List<string>();
     grades.EnterGrades(addedStudents);
     break;
```

However, I think there's more wrong with the whole thing from ground up.

Comment: I think there's more wrong with the whole thing from ground up - are you trying to suggest that's naming a variable `get` is not a good idea? ;)

Comment: Bold design choice?

Comment: Ohhh, that'll be my new go-to-phrase in code reviews starting tomorrow!

Comment: Thanks @JesseC.Slicer